# Using Radio Buttons with a Date Picker Dialog and blocking out previous dates

Tags: java, android, datepicker, dialog, radio-button

I'm an amateur programmer in school and trying to create a specific app in my class but the professor refuses to help us and clearly says the materials needed are not in the book we have...Anyways, I'm trying to build an app for tablets that will use Radio buttons to allow the user to make a selection of GPU parts, confirm the selection, then use a date picker to request the day that the pc order is placed and when it will be shipped. I'm having blank thoughts how to go about blocking out previous days or how to utilize the radio buttons in the app at all. I know how to create the date picker and push the date out, but thats all i have.

```
package edu.wmich.lab4rfoste1057;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView calReservation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        calReservation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtChoice);
        final RadioButton rad970 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad970);
        final RadioButton rad980 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad980);
        final RadioButton rad390 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad390);
        final RadioButton radFury = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radFury);

        Button btnResults = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResults);

        btnResults.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, theDate,    calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),    calDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
    }


    Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();



    DateFormat fmtDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener theDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
          public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int    dayOfMonth) {



            calDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth+1);



              calReservation.setText("Your Computer will be built on " +          fmtDate.format(calDate.getTime()));


        }
    };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear about what exactly you are looking to learn about RadioButtons. You can learn about them here though:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

You can set the minimum and maximum date by using the DatePicker from the DatePickerDialog:

```
DatePicker picker = dialog.getDatePicker();
picker.setMinDate(long);
picker.setMaxDate(long);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)

Comment: Thank you for the help. in terms of the radio buttons, i have to present 4 options to the user, in this case 4 different gpus. I then have to bring up the calendar dialog and have the user pick a date to place the order, in which i wanted to block out all the days before the current system date, and then once the user makes the selection a textview on the bottom will appear and say "Your order was placed...current date".

Comment: You can do that with the code that you already have. Within your onDateSet listener method, you can check which GPU the user has selected. For example, rad970.isChecked() will tell you if "Rad970" is selected.